# How to convert a bootstrap theme to the yii-bootstrap extension?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Recently, I've started using the Yii framework to develop a personal website. I would love to use some of the bootstrap themes that have already been implemented; however, I'm having difficulty finding a way to convert these themes to the yii framework.

Is there any way to download a bootstrap theme and then convert it to the yii framework? What are the basic steps I should take? (or, better) Is there any converter out there that does this automatically?

Comment: No need to thank in the question :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/2886891

Answer (score 0):

Download Bootstrap ..

Then create move it to project_name/themes and rename it to bootstrap

edit this protected/config/main.php and add this line :

```
'theme' => 'bootstrap',
```

Like:

```
'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
'name'=>'My Web Application',
'theme' => 'bootstrap',
```

to call the script or the styles use the theme request url, like:

Script:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/js/boostrap.js">
```

Style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo Yii::app()->theme->baseUrl;?>/css/boostrap.css">
```

This can be use on other themes.

Cheers!

Comment: Ian, I'm a bit confused. I know that this works for themes that already have been integrated into the yii framework (i.e. blackboot), but I've tried it with other bootstrap themes from themeforest without simply being able to insert in the name of the them after 'theme'=>'bootstrap',